# typeorm save calls more than 1000 times in custom logger

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to implement Custom Logger for typeorm with nestJs. my goal is to store queries in MySQL.

First I create an entity:

```
@Entity('log')
export class LogModel extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({ nullable: true, type: "text" })
    query: string

}
```

then create a custom logger class like the following :

```
import { Logger, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm'

export class CustomLogger implements Logger {

    logQuery(query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {
        this.saveLog(queryRunner)
    }

    private async saveLog(queryRunner: QueryRunner) {
        if (queryRunner) {
            const log = new LogModel()
            log.query='my query ....'

            const repository = queryRunner.connection.getRepository<LogModel>(LogModel)
            await repository.save(log) // calls more than 1000
        }
    }

    logQueryError(error: string | Error, query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {}

    logQuerySlow(time: number, query: string, parameters?: any[], queryRunner?: QueryRunner) {}

    logSchemaBuild(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) { }
    logMigration(message: string, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) { }

    log(level: 'log' | 'info' | 'warn', message: any, queryRunner?: QueryRunner) { }
}
```

and in the last step I use the CustomLogger class above in typeorm config:

```
const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    logging: ['warn', 'error'],
    charset: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/migrations'
    },
    ....
    maxQueryExecutionTime: 1000,
    logger: new CustomLogger()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've created a recursive function. You run a query, that calls the logger, that runs a query that calls the logger that runs a query that calls the logger (etc.). You'd need to probably use a database driver directly to not interfere with the TypeORM query cycle and to keep the logging queries separate from the regular queries.

Comment: could you please direct me How to do that? can you introduce a repository?

Comment: How to do what? Use the database driver directly?